# Objects invisible in any view except Solid

Tags: rendering

In any blender scene, objects look transparent or invisible in all views except solid mode. Is there a setting i should check? This has happened ever since i had blender and i couldn't fix it
[image: rendered mode]

[image: material preview]

[image: wireframe mode]

The pics are of just a brand new scene, nothing touched. Is this normal?